How to update PDF file using itext while it is open with PdfiumViewer in c#?
I have a small Windows Forms application. It is supposed to open a PDF file, then put a stamp on it. Afterward, the updated document should be display for the user to see the change.
However, I am having some troubles updating the PDF.
I am using PdfiumViewer.PdfRenderer to display the document:
    private void LoadPdf(string pdfPath)
    {
        pdfDocument = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(pdfPath);
        pdfRenderer.Load(pdfDocument);            
    }

Then I am using itext to put a stamp on it:
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
        using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfPath))
        using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter))
        {
            pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(true);
            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

            // Add a stamp at the captured position
            Paragraph stamp = new Paragraph("bababa")
                .SetFixedPosition(1, pdfX, pdfY, 50)
                .SetFontSize(12)
                .SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);

            document.Add(stamp);
            
        }
        LoadPdf(pdfPath);

The "PDFWriter" gives me an error, that file is used by another process (I guess PdfiumViewer.PdfRenderer locks it). So I wanted to ask how can I "unlock" the file for the stamping process.
I know that I can kind of achieve this by saving the stamped document as another file and then opening it, but that resets the display of the PDF on Renderer and the user has to scroll/zoom back again. That is why I want to do it using 1 file.
If it is not possible to do it using 1 file, what are the best practices for such app?
Edit:
Tried saving file to MemoryStream first as per @mkl's suggestion, but without sucess:
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();           
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
        using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memStream))
        using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter))
        {
            pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(true);
            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

            // Add a stamp at the captured position
            Paragraph stamp = new Paragraph("bababa")
                .SetFixedPosition(1, pdfX, pdfY, 50)
                .SetFontSize(12)
                .SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);

            document.Add(stamp);
            
        }
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            memStream.Position = 0; // Reset the position to the beginning of the stream
            memStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

Still the same error, but now when trying to write MemoryStream to PDF

You can target a MemoryStream with the PdfWriter and after disposing of the PdfReader and PdfWriter you can store the contents of that MemoryStream to the file.

@mkl I tried to save output first to MemoryStream first, but encountered the same error. I think it is because pdfRenderer "locks" the document, and not itext. I edited the question with memoryStream attempt.

There is, however, an option to load PDF to renderer from the MemoryStream (using PdfiumViewer.IPdfDocument instead of PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument). But I am not quite sure how to properly do it, especially with updates.

First, determine how to restore the user's scroll and zoom settings when closing your program entirely then re-opening.  Many standalone PDF viewers support this.  PdfiumViewer might have an option for this.  If you get that working, the solution is 1. Close the PDF renderer (that will release the Windows file lock). 2. Modify the PDF. 3. Re-open the renderer, restoring the scroll and zoom settings.

@MatthewFlaschen This was also my first thought. I was able to get Zoom level to work, since you can easily retrieve zoom level and then set it back. Scrolling is a bit harder, since you need to first get bounds(a zone, that user saw before, if I understood that correctly), and then you can scroll back to that zone. I decided to leave it as a backup plan, since I thought that there might be better options.

"I think it is because pdfRenderer "locks" the document, and not itext." - In that case you may additionally need some file sharing options for Pdfium. But in your code with the MemoryStream you use a FileStream constructor without a FileShare argument. Maybe you should use a different constructor and allow as much FileShare options as possible/sensible.
